# Add css styles to list item pattern

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm using a html `ul` for display some datas

```css
#myList li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  min-height: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li style="background: #f9f9f9">Two</li>
  <li style="background: #f9f9f9">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li style="background: #f9f9f9">Six</li>
  <li style="background: #f9f9f9">Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li style="background: #f9f9f9">Ten</li>
  <li style="background: #f9f9f9">Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
</ul>
```

My design is

[image]

I'm currently using inline styles for show the background colors,

can anyone help me to to apply this kind styles using normal CSS via some pseudo selectors please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#myList li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  min-height: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}

#myList li:nth-child(4n + 2), li:nth-child(4n + 3){
     background: #f9f9f9
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
</ul>
```